# Is it possible to consume an API with express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express.js

I have a problem, I wanted to create an API with express to consume another API, but I don't know how to do it ... Could you help me?

Comment: Este é o stackoverflow em Português.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Sendo bem direto, sim, é possível consumir uma API Rest usando Express, você não vai bem consumir a API com o Express, mas sim com bibliotecas para fazer requisições, como o Axios por exemplo. Então, se a sua ideia é: Estou usando o Framework Express, e quero usar uma API externa de alguma forma na minha aplicação, a resposta é sim, é possível.

Agora que vem os poréns e as variantes:

**Que API é esta?**
Exemplo: A API do Github

**Qual seu objetivo ao utilizar essa API?**
Exemplo: Quero buscar dados do usuário para a minha aplicação, ou quero usar o oAuth do Github para autenticação dos usuários, e etc.

Há estas e mais diversas perguntas que você deve se fazer ao consumir uma API, mas o principal que você deve ter em mãos é: ***o seu objetivo com essa API, a documentação dela, e se essa API tem uma SDK para você usar com a linguagem que você está utilizando.***

Você conseguirá mais detalhes fazendo uma pergunta mais específica, então, é com você :)

Comment: Quero buscar dados de usuarios de uma API externa(api traccar) para minha aplicação, utilizando axios JS e depois mandar esses dados para um servidor criado com express. Como posso fazer isso?